# Conversion from xhtml to html

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

How does the conversion happen from xhtml to html ? whatever we coded in xhtml is displayed in HTML format when we view the page source in browser. How it happens. Is it because of < !DOCTYPE >. if so what is the role of DOCTYPE in conversion from xhtml to html

Answer (score 3):

The [Doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration) is a declaration which tells the browser what is the type of HTML code in the page. That has nothing to do with JSF and with any *conversion from xhtml to html*.

What you call *conversion* is done by JSF. You have somewhere in your `web.xml` the following configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To simplify, the `FacesServlet` interprets the XHTML code to produce the HTML file returned to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The actual conversion is done by JSF framework. While executing the last phase "Render Response" each component in jsf will have a respective java render class while will parse the component into plain html which you are able to see in page view source.